# XSLT & XPath very complex data transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, serialization, xpath

I am working on something where data is delivered in various XML formats, and although I can figure out most of the pieces of how to parse it, I do not know enough about XSLT and XPath to know where to begin putting together this type of multiple transform, where some data is obviously just looked up, some data is repeating, elements have to be renamed, some data is in attributes and some in values, and templates probably have to be processed in specific order or be called with variables.  I don't think there is this type example present here, and if we could get one, it might solve a lot of issues for people.

The goal is to take input from several sources which provide similar data in different forms, translate them to a common XML form, and write only ONE (1) progam processing path, instead of the four (4) that we now have to maintain. Also, the translation should be easy to deserialize.

Any way, here is a fair example of an INPUT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PackageName TransmissionID="0792d49a-c09b-4094-9f4e-2357a042865c">
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <DateReported>04/12/2010</DateReported>
  <TimeReported>10:16:46.9385105</TimeReported>
  <!-- Status=Disposition -->
  <ReportPackage Status="Disposition1">
    <Addresses>
      <Address>
        <!-- PersonAddress -->
        <Name>Stephen Stipulate</Name>
        <Address>1200 Any Street</Address>
        <City>Some City</City>
        <State>XX</State>
        <Zip>12345</Zip>
        <Phone>800-555-1212</Phone>
      </Address>
    </Addresses>
    <Parts packageID="APackageId">
      <packageClientAccount>00000000</packageClientAccount>
      <DiscardedIdentifier id="NothingOfInterest">
        <AssemblyId>
          <IdValue>0547224801-0908</IdValue>
        </AssemblyId>
        <!-- Status -->
        <AssemblyStatus>
          <Status>OutOfStock</Status>
          <DateReOrderReceived>2009-09-24T06:09:00</DateReOrderReceived>
        </AssemblyStatus>
        <PartVendor>
          <!-- VendorAddress -->
          <VendorName>Roger Refactor</VendorName>
          <VendorAddress>
            <IdValue name="Address">100 An Avenue Suite 13</IdValue>
            <IdValue name="City">A Different City</IdValue>
            <IdValue name="State">YY</IdValue>
            <IdValue name="Zip">54321</IdValue>
            <IdValue name="Phone">866-555-1212</IdValue>
          </VendorAddress>
        </PartVendor>
        <PartsMainSegment>
          <AdditionalSegment>
            <PartSpecs>
              <Spec>
                <PartId>123456</PartId>
                <Name>Widget1</Name>
                <ThresholdLevel>000500</ThresholdLevel>
              </Spec>
              <Spec>
                <PartId>234567</PartId>
                <Name>Widget2</Name>
                <ThresholdLevel>000200</ThresholdLevel>
              </Spec>
            </PartSpecs>
          </AdditionalSegment>
        </PartsMainSegment>
        <AdditionallPartsSegment>
          <Spec>
            <PartId>123456</PartId>
            <PartType>ABC</PartType>
          </Spec>
          <Spec>
            <PartId>234567</PartId>
            <PartType>CBA</PartType>
          </Spec>
        </AdditionallPartsSegment>
        <AdditionalItems type="RawData" qualifier="mode" vendor="rogerRefactor">
          <Text>AModeValue</Text>
        </AdditionalItems>
        <AdditionalItems type="RawData" qualifier="indicator" vendor="rogerRefactor">
          <Text>AnIndicator</Text>
        </AdditionalItems>
      </DiscardedIdentifier>
    </Parts>
  </ReportPackage>
</PackageName>
```

And the desired OUTPUT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package>
  <TransmissionID>0792d49a-c09b-4094-9f4e-2357a042865c</TransmissionID>
  <PackageType>PackageName</PackageType>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <DateReported>1/03/2011</DateReported>
  <TimeReported>16:25:35.1293170</TimeReported>
  <Disposition>Disposition1</Disposition>>
  <packageID>APackageId</packageID>
  <packageClientAccount>00000000</packageClientAccount>
  <Addresses>
    <PersonAddress>
      <Name>Stephen Stipulate</Name>
      <Address>1200 Any Street</Address>
      <City>Some City</City>
      <State>XX</State>
      <Zip>12345</Zip>
      <Phone>800-555-1212</Phone>
    </PersonAddress>
    <VendorAddress>
      <Name>Roger Refactor</Name>
      <Address>100 An Avenue Suite 13</Address>
      <City>A Different City</City>
      <State>YY</State>
      <Zip>54321</Zip>
      <Phone>866-555-1212</Phone>
    </VendorAddress>
  </Addresses>
  <Parts>
    <AssemblyId id="0547224801-0908">
      <Status>OutOfStock</Status>
      <DateReOrderReceived>2009-09-24T06:09:00</DateReOrderReceived>
      <Part>
        <PartId>123456</PartId>
        <PartName>Widget1</PartName>
        <Level>000500</Level>
        <PartType>ABC</PartType>
      </Part>
      <Part>
        <PartId>234567</PartId>
        <PartNameName>Widget2</PartNameName>
        <Level>000200</Level>
        <PartType>CBA</PartType>
      </Part>
    </AssemblyId>
  </Parts>
  <AdditionalData>
    <Vendor>TheVendor</Vendor>
    <Mode>AModeValue</Mode>
    <Indicator>AnIndicator</Indicator>
  </AdditionalData>
</Package>
```

We actually get XML similar to this reporting to a web service. Notice the required re-names, movement of data to different parts of the tree, and also in particular the different segments which have to be joined to make a list of part records, which do not have a parent/child relation.  I am not offering any bad starting attempt, as I am at a loss as to where to start on this since I simply don't understand how to sequence the processing, and I am certain that somebody out there (Dimitre!), while not on purpose, would make me look like an idiot! :)

Well thanks for any and all help - cheers! :)

Comment: Can we assume that elements in the input file will always be in the same order as in your example? Also, is XSLT 2.0 a possibility, or are you stuck with 1.0?

Comment: Yes, they will always be in the same order, but I have four of these to do (three different from this one) and am looking for a seed to get started :) I think 2.0 is cool, will be using the .NET XSLT engine. If there are typos, I apologize, but basically, this is what has to be done - un-obfuscate the input XML... :)

Comment: I am not sure what the question/problem is - you can just write a template matching `PackageName` and then create the corresponding `Package` copying the values in the right element/attribute - using `<xsl:value-of..>` and `<xsl:copy-of...>`.

Comment: Thanks Borodin... exactly what I needed to just get a handle on how to proceed.  The input of course was kind of cobbled together and not real world data (which might be sensitive!!!) so the typos were expected.  Very much appreciate your example, and it indeed does simplify my task(s) greatly! - h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff like this is really quite simple, and mostly a matter of writing a single template and pulling out informtion form the XML tree using XPath selectors.

It's not clear whether some items can occur several times - `VendorAddress` for instance - but this transform at least creates the output you require from the input you gave.

There is a problem with `Package/AdditionalData/Vendor`, as you say you want a value of `TheVendor` but this string doesn't appear in the source data. I have pulled it instead from `PartVendor/VendorName`. There is also nothing to tie that name in with the `vendor="rogerRefactor"` attribute of the `AdditionalItems`, but I'm sure you'll get these things sorted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/PackageName">
        <Package>
            <TransmissionID><xsl:value-of select="@TransmissionID"/></TransmissionID>
            <PackageType>PackageName</PackageType>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Version"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="DateReported"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="TimeReported"/>
            <Disposition><xsl:value-of select="ReportPackage/@Status"/></Disposition>
            <packageID><xsl:value-of select="ReportPackage/Parts/@packageID"/></packageID>
            <packageClientAccount><xsl:value-of select="ReportPackage/Parts/packageClientAccount"/></packageClientAccount>
            <Addresses>
                <PersonAddress>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportPackage/Addresses/Address"/>
                </PersonAddress>
                <VendorAddress>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportPackage/Parts//PartVendor"/>
                </VendorAddress>
            </Addresses>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportPackage/Parts"/>
            <AdditionalData>
                <Vendor><xsl:value-of select=".//PartVendor/VendorName"/></Vendor>
                <Mode><xsl:value-of select=".//AdditionalItems[@qualifier='mode']/Text"/></Mode>
                <Indicator><xsl:value-of select=".//AdditionalItems[@qualifier='indicator']/Text"/></Indicator>
            </AdditionalData>
        </Package>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parts">
        <Parts>
            <AssemblyId>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select=".//AssemblyId/IdValue"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <Status><xsl:value-of select=".//AssemblyStatus/Status"/></Status>
                <DateReOrderReceived><xsl:value-of select=".//AssemblyStatus/DateReOrderReceived"/></DateReOrderReceived>
                <xsl:for-each select=".//PartsMainSegment/AdditionalSegment/PartSpecs/Spec">
                    <Part>
                        <xsl:variable name="part-id" select="PartId"/>
                        <PartId><xsl:value-of select="PartId"/></PartId>
                        <PartName><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></PartName>
                        <Level><xsl:value-of select="ThresholdLevel"/></Level>
                        <PartType><xsl:value-of select="//AdditionallPartsSegment/Spec[PartId = $part-id]/PartType"/></PartType>
                    </Part>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </AssemblyId>
        </Parts>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Address">
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></Name>
        <Address><xsl:value-of select="Address"/></Address>
        <City><xsl:value-of select="City"/></City>
        <State><xsl:value-of select="State"/></State>
        <Zip><xsl:value-of select="Zip"/></Zip>
        <Phone><xsl:value-of select="Phone"/></Phone>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PartVendor">
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="VendorName"/></Name>
        <Address><xsl:value-of select="VendorAddress/IdValue[@name='Address']"/></Address>
        <City><xsl:value-of select="VendorAddress/IdValue[@name='City']"/></City>
        <State><xsl:value-of select="VendorAddress/IdValue[@name='State']"/></State>
        <Zip><xsl:value-of select="VendorAddress/IdValue[@name='Zip']"/></Zip>
        <Phone><xsl:value-of select="VendorAddress/IdValue[@name='Phone']"/></Phone>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package>
   <TransmissionID>0792d49a-c09b-4094-9f4e-2357a042865c</TransmissionID>
   <PackageType>PackageName</PackageType>
   <Version>1.0</Version>
   <DateReported>04/12/2010</DateReported>
   <TimeReported>10:16:46.9385105</TimeReported>
   <Disposition>Disposition1</Disposition>
   <packageID>APackageId</packageID>
   <packageClientAccount>00000000</packageClientAccount>
   <Addresses>
      <PersonAddress>
         <Name>Stephen Stipulate</Name>
         <Address>1200 Any Street</Address>
         <City>Some City</City>
         <State>XX</State>
         <Zip>12345</Zip>
         <Phone>800-555-1212</Phone>
      </PersonAddress>
      <VendorAddress>
         <Name>Roger Refactor</Name>
         <Address>100 An Avenue Suite 13</Address>
         <City>A Different City</City>
         <State>YY</State>
         <Zip>54321</Zip>
         <Phone>866-555-1212</Phone>
      </VendorAddress>
   </Addresses>
   <Parts>
      <AssemblyId id="0547224801-0908">
         <Status>OutOfStock</Status>
         <DateReOrderReceived>2009-09-24T06:09:00</DateReOrderReceived>
         <Part>
            <PartId>123456</PartId>
            <PartName>Widget1</PartName>
            <Level>000500</Level>
            <PartType>ABC</PartType>
         </Part>
         <Part>
            <PartId>234567</PartId>
            <PartName>Widget2</PartName>
            <Level>000200</Level>
            <PartType>CBA</PartType>
         </Part>
      </AssemblyId>
   </Parts>
   <AdditionalData>
      <Vendor>Roger Refactor</Vendor>
      <Mode>AModeValue</Mode>
      <Indicator>AnIndicator</Indicator>
   </AdditionalData>
</Package>
```

Comment: Thanks Borodin... exactly what I needed to just get a handle on how to proceed.  The input of course was kind of cobbled together and not real world data (which might be sensitive!!!) so the typos were expected.  Very much appreciate your example, and it indeed does simplify my task(s) greatly! - h.

Comment: @HRJ, typos are understandable, but cobbled-together input needs to be carefully checked to make sure it accurately represents the relevant characteristics of the real data. One of the most annoying things for an answerer is when they work hard analyzing the sample input, craft a solution, and then are told that various aspects of the sample input don't really represent the real data. The presence of typos shows that the asker didn't carefully check the sample input.

Comment: My apologies, I did spend a good deal of time on it, but was trying to emulate issues found in several differing inputs - all of which your example handled more than sufficiently, in order to bootstrap further efforts.  One of the problems was that I had to change the name of every element and fake in all data because the actual task is to decipher very sensitive personal data received from major providers, and anything close to resembling the actual input and format could not be included.  I am EXTREMELY pleased with your response, as it perfectly clarified the approach to the task. Cheers :)